# How can I mix Guice and Jersey injection?

Tags: java, jersey, guice

I've already seen [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556495/jersey-guice-cant-mix-non-jersey-resources-with-jersey-resources) on how to inject `@Context` dependencies into Jersey resource constructors. But my question is slightly different -- I'd like to inject a `@PathParam` String. I have a class resembling the following:

```
@Path("foo/{fooId}/bar")
public class BarResource {
  @Inject
  public BarResource(@PathParam("fooId") String foo, Service service) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

The `Service` is injected fine by Guice, but the path segment is always null. This actually surprises me; if anything I assumed Guice would loudly explode complaining about an unresolvable dependency.

How can I inject a path parameter in this manner? I would prefer to avoid field injection for the purposes of keeping these resource classes unit-testable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `@PathParam` is not acceptable by default as a `Constructor` argument. This [new feature document](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/mhadley/archive/2007/09/new_jersey_feat.html) states

> The arguments allowed in a resource class constructor depends on the resource provider used to create an instance of the resource class [...]. For default per-request resource classes you can use any combination of parameters annotated with UriParam, UriParam, QueryParam, MatrixParam, HeaderParam or HttpContext.

You could provide your own resource provider that processes the `@PathParam` annotation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by saying it's not in the context of handling a request. It's not bound as a Singleton; when I trace it in the debugger, the constructor is indeed invoked upon the HTTP request. From the Jersey docs: "JAX-RS resources are managed in per-request scope by default which means that new resource is created for each request."

Comment: Additionally, I can inject a `UriInfo` and access the fooId path segment from that. But it's messier and I'd like to keep this constructor as POJO-ish as possible. Hence, I'd like to know if there's any way to use the `@PathParam` annotation as intended.

Comment: @TomG Seems the default resource provider doesn't allow `@PathParam`.

Comment: @TomG Forget anything I said for now. Try annotating a field of the class with `@PathParam`, because [this](http://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html) says that it should work.

Comment: I see -- well that's a bummer. Still, thanks for at least confirming that I shouldn't burn more time on it.

Comment: @TomG Wowo, slow down lol. Check the link I had in my previous comment.