# How can I use Jersey's @QueryParam and Guice injection in a resource constructor?

Tags: java, jersey, guice

I am trying to use Jersey's `@QueryParam` and Guice's `@Inject` together in a resource constructor. From looking on the web, there have been similar questions to mine asked before:
[How can I mix Guice and Jersey injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489529/how-can-i-mix-guice-and-jersey-injection)
http://users.jersey.dev.java.narkive.com/zlGMXuBe/can-queryparam-be-used-in-resource-constructor-along-with-guice-injection

It seems it is not possible. However, these questions are several years old, so is what I'm trying to do possible now?

Here's some code of what I'm trying to do as an example:

```
@Path("/mypath")
public class MyResource {
  private Manager manager;
  private String type;

  @Inject
  public MyResource(Manager manager,
                    @QueryParam("type") String type) {
    this.manager = manager;
    this.type = type;
  }

  @GET
  @Produces("text/plan")
  @Path("/{period}")
  public String myMethod(@PathParam("period") String period) {
    return manager.foo(period, type);
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't make sense? `MyResource` is a singleton and handles all requests. At the time of construction there is no request and hence no `@QueryParam`.

Comment: @LanceJava If you remove the Guice `@Inject` stuff, it works. You can pass in a query parameter with the request and the constructor will set it to whatever you passed in.

Comment: Ok, not a Jersey user myself. Spring mvc etc use singletons rather than per request event handlers. I can only assume you'll need to plug guice into the Jersey injector somehow

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Maybe is a problem related to the correct binding of Jersey and Guice.

I created a minimal web application with your resource definition and some boilerplate code.

First the app initialization:

```
@WebListener
@Singleton
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        new GuiceBootstrap().contextInitialized(sce);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // no op
    }
}
```

You can see there that I initialize Guice there. Here is the Guice code.

```
public class GuiceBootstrap extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector((Module) binder -> binder.bind(Manager.class)
                                                             .to(ManagerImpl.class));
    }
}
```

It is Java 8 syntax but if you're not using Java 8 it is easily convertible to pre-lambda code. I create a Guice injector with just one binding.

The `Manager` and implementation class are very simple.

```
public interface Manager {
    String foo(String period, String type);
}

public class ManagerImpl implements Manager {
    @Override
    public String foo(String period, String type) {
        return "Got " + period + " " + type;
    }
}
```

Finally the code that initialices Jersey and binds its internal injector (HK2) to Guice.

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApiRest extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    public ApiRest(ServiceLocator serviceLocator, ServletContext servletContext) {
        packages("net.sargue.so38531044");
        GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);
        GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
        Injector injector = (Injector) servletContext.getAttribute(Injector.class.getName());
        if (injector == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Guice Injector not found");
        guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(injector);
    }
}
```